# In Condition, using substr

Tags: sql, oracle11g, excel-2010

I want to get all the data from the column, but my source will only give me part of the information on that same column, for example my source will give me the following data (Not inserted on the DB, excel file):

```
Id_Source
----------------
ABC
A1B
B23
CGT
TGR
FRT
```

And my oracle table information looks like this:

```
Id
----------------
ABC__120116
A1B__130115
B23__123534
CGT__125347
TGR__456873
FRT__124652
```

I tried to do it using a substr function, but it doesnt seem to work, here is what I have so far.

```
select id
from Tbl1
where
id in (substr('ABC',1,3));
```

I also tried it with an OR conditional which works, but I have thousands of records and the search takes too long.

```
 select id 
from tbl1
where
and (
transaction_id like 'ABC%' or
transaction_id like 'A1B%' or
transaction_id like 'B23%');
```

Is there any way to get the in conditional with substring, or any other way to make the search faster?

Comment: are these 2 different tables? or is one of them not in the db?

Comment: The Id_source is not on the DB, its an excel file

Comment: it would be a simple query if you could import the excel as a table into the database.

Comment: Can't, Dont have the privileges to create tables on the DB, not even Views or physical objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
where substr(transaction_id, 1, 3) in ('ABC', 'A1B', 'B23', 'CGT', 'TGR', 'FRT')
```

This may work faster with a function-based index:

```
create index idx_t_transaction_id on t(substr(transaction_id, 1, 3));
```

Comment: Yes it Works! Thank you!

Comment: But it still takes way too long to send the results, and the column ID is indexed.